# Chart C# Заменить числа на Ох (1,2,3...) на (Pi/2,Pi,...)

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Сам интервал мы меняем `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = Math.PI;` , а вот как заменить сами числа на оси Ох ? тобишь, чтоб вместо 1,2,3,4.. было Pi/2,Pi ..

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, как вы добавляете точки в коллекцию `Points` объекта типа `Series`.

Если добавлять точки без явного указания значения X, например с помощью [DataPointCollection.Add (Double[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd455986(v=vs.110).aspx), то в качестве значений X, будут подставлены порядковые номера точек в порядке их добавления в коллекцию, разумеется целые =), что вы и наблюдаете.

Чтобы по оси X видеть нужные значения, для добавления точек необходимо воспользоваться одной из перегрузок метода `DataPointCollection.AddXY` ([для чисел](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd456166(v=vs.110).aspx), [для любых значений. включая текст](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd467884(v=vs.110).aspx)). В этом случае, под каждой точкой будут проставлены те значения X, которые вы укажете в первом параметре метода.

В свойствах осей можно задать параметры отображения сетки, параметры отображения точек определяются в `Series`, для всех точек, или в самих `DataPoint`, индивидуально для каждой.